# Hibernate 2nd level query caching generates queries on hits

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, ehcache

As stated in the title, I see a behaviour for which I wasn't able to find an answer that would actually explain or help to understand whether my cache for queries works or not.

What I have is:

1. An entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE, region = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private String productId;
```

2. Repository

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {

    @QueryHints({
            @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")
    })
    Optional<Customer> findByProductId(String productId);

}
```

3. application.yaml

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: test
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate:
        ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      javax:
        persistence:
          sharedCache:
            mode: ENABLE_SELECTIVE
      hibernate:
        generate_statistics: true
        cache:
          use_second_level_cache: true
          use_query_cache: true
          region:
            factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory
        javax:
          cache:
            provider: org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider
            #missing_cache_strategy: fail
            uri: ehcache.xml
```

4. ehcache config

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.ehcache.org/v3"
        xmlns:jsr107="http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.0.xsd
            http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-107-ext-3.0.xsd">

    <cache alias="customer">
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="seconds">15</ttl>
        </expiry>
        <resources>
            <heap unit="entries">1000</heap>
            <offheap unit="MB">100</offheap>
        </resources>
    </cache>

</config>
```

5. Test

```
@Test
public void test() {
        // setup
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setProductId("product_1");

        customerRepository.persist(customer);

        // test
        customerRepository.findByProductId("product1");
        customerRepository.findByProductId("product1");
        customerRepository.findByProductId("product1");
        customerRepository.findByProductId("product2");
        customerRepository.findByProductId("product2");
        customerRepository.findByProductId("product1");
        customerRepository.findByProductId("product1");
        customerRepository.findById(customer.getId());
        customerRepository.findById(customer.getId());
        customerRepository.findById(customer.getId());
}
```

When the test is executed I see the following statistics:

```
...
Hibernate: select c1_0.id,c1_0.product_id from customer c1_0 where c1_0.product_id=?
Hibernate: select c1_0.id,c1_0.product_id from customer c1_0 where c1_0.product_id=?
Hibernate: select c1_0.id,c1_0.product_id from customer c1_0 where c1_0.product_id=?
Hibernate: select c1_0.id,c1_0.product_id from customer c1_0 where c1_0.product_id=?
Hibernate: select c1_0.id,c1_0.product_id from customer c1_0 where c1_0.product_id=?
Hibernate: select c1_0.id,c1_0.product_id from customer c1_0 where c1_0.product_id=?
Hibernate: select c1_0.id,c1_0.product_id from customer c1_0 where c1_0.product_id=?

2023-07-26T13:52:14.245+01:00  INFO 98236 --- [    Test worker] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
    804750 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    2941542 nanoseconds spent preparing 9 JDBC statements;
    11014291 nanoseconds spent executing 9 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    14025208 nanoseconds spent performing 9 L2C puts;
    1288917 nanoseconds spent performing 10 L2C hits;
    154709 nanoseconds spent performing 2 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    2719793 nanoseconds spent executing 8 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 7 entities and 7 collections)
```

From what we see, hibernate still generates queries and executes them. So the cache isn't actually working, right? If such so, what am I might be missing?

**UPDATE:** I have 2 different sources which point to the different DBs and I just have discovered that this behaviour only happens for the Data Source which is set as @Primary. For the alternative one, there are no queries being generated if there is a hit. How can I fix it for the @Primary data source?